# Impress.js & Using HTML5 Data Attributes Instead of CSS Transforms

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms, custom-data-attribute

I've been working on a presentation using [Impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/), and was thinking of adapting it for use on iPads. But I'm concerned about how Impress applies transforms to each slide. Instead of just using CSS, transforms are put in the HTML as data attributes, then applied with Javascript.

This strikes me as an overly complicated and difficult way of doing things. I don't have a lot of experience working with data attributes, though, so I wanted to get some opinions on this. Would it be better to just write CSS normally, or do the benefits of using data attributes outweigh the hassle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simple: if you set a CSS transformation—either through javascript or CSS—when you try to get it it returns a matrix transformation. So say you do something simple like...

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(10px,0,0)";
var transform = element.style.webkitTransform;
```

`transform` won't be `translate3d(10px,0,0)`, it will be `matrix3d(10px,0,0,[...])`. To get these values you'd need to parse the matrix such as...

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(10px,0,0)";
var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(element.style.webkitTransform); //get the matrix
var x = matrix.m41 //get the value of x in the matrix
x += 1500 //modify x
element.style.webkitTransform = matrix.toString //Apply the new transformation
```

This is the same code with data-attr:

```
  element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(10px,0,0)";
  x = element.dataset.x
  element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + x + ",0,0)"
```

You can play around with the 3D CSS Matrix here:

http://jsfiddle.net/F8xLv/

Comment: So it's better to use data attributes than to have to parse the matrix, because the latter is even more complicated than the prior? It seems like the method you demonstrated above, though, would be just as effective and no more difficult to implement.

Comment: I updated the answer with a dataset example, I think it is much more readable.